# How to print the entire tag strcuture in a org.jdom.Document object?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, jdom

I am very new in **XML Parsing** in Java and I have the following question:

If in my Java code I have something like:

```
org.jdom.Document documentXML = builder.build(new StringReader(myResponse));
System.out.println("documentXML:\n" + documentXML.toString());
```

When I go to execute the previous commands I obtain the following output:

```
documentXML:
[Document:  No DOCTYPE declaration, Root is [Element: <s:Envelope [Namespace: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/]/>]]
objectElement: [Element: <s:Body [Namespace: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/]/>]
```

It seems to me that I am not seeing the entire content of my Document object. What have I to do to see the entire tags in this object?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Your other recent question indicates you are using JDOM 2.0.x .... make sure you are using only one version of JDOM (org.jdom2.Document for JDOM 2.x and org.jdom.document for JDOM 1.x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to use the XMLOutputter class. You could do:

```
new XmlOutputter().output(document, System.out);
```

You can also specify a format. If you desire pretty-printing:

```
 new XmlOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat()).output(document, System.out);
```

The documentation is available [here](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs.1.1/org/jdom/output/XMLOutputter.html#output%28org.jdom.Document,%20java.io.OutputStream%29).

Comment: mmm the problem is that the typy of my object documentXML is org.jdom.Document and not Document, so it go into error and say to me to change the type of this variable into Document...but I don't know ot Document and org.jdom.Document are the same thing...I also tryied to do a cast but it is impossible

Comment: I method is actually expecting a org.jdom.Document. just calling the method `output()` with your documentXML object should work fine.